# how to change space before code in vs code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

in my vscode there is too space for formating
[image]

im getting this only when i am using java script
what i want to be is something like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it in

`File > Preferences > Settings > Tab Size`

```
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
```

and set the number of spaces.

Comment: how to access Preferences  location?

Comment: Press `File` in the top bar